# Rewrite subdomain exactly like the main website

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I'm currently working on a blog portal, and I'm trying to achieve a specific thing here.

This is my .htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.[NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+?)\.MyDomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ blogdisplay.php?page=%1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ index.php?page=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/$ index.php?page=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ index.php?page=$1&page2=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/$ index.php?page=$1&page2=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ index.php?    page=$1&page2=$2&page3=$3
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/$ index.php?page=$1&page2=$2&page3=$3
```

When a person is trying to reach SOMETHING.mydomain.com, htaccess is rewriting it to blogdisplay.php?page=BLOGNAME. Just as planned. Now, the problem is that I want it to behave exactly like the main website and rewrite SOMETHING.mydomain.com/page to blogdisplay.php?page=BLOGNAME?page2=page.

Is there any way to make the subdomain use blogdisplay.php instead of index.php, but otherwise work exactly like the subpages of the "main website"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your code with this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.[NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+?)\.MyDomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ blogdisplay.php?page=%1 [L,QSA]

## If the request is for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
## don't do anything
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+?)\.MyDomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ blogdisplay.php?page=%1&page2=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&page2=$2 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&page2=$2&page3=$3 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Oh, seems like there's a little problem... When I'm trying to reach example.mydomain.com/page it works fine, but when trying to reach example.mydomain.com it rewrites to just mydomain.com.

Comment: Nah, now it's back at the original issue... But I made a little tweak and added: RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.[NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+?)\.loglime.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ blogdisplay.php?page=%1 [L,QSA] (this works)

Comment: Yes that will definitely work, I was just trying to avoid an extra rule :P